# HoloLens2に付いているカメラから輝度の値を得たい。

Tags: c#, unity3d, api

C#(Unity)でHoloLens2に映し出すコンテンツ制作に興味があり取り掛かり始めました。
そこで、自然光が多いと、HoloLens2のホログラム(CG)の色が薄くなることに不便を感じています。
ホログラムを表示するときの輝度を調整したいので、せっかくですから、HoloLens2に内蔵されているハンドトラッキング用のカメラからHoloLens2が置かれている環境についての輝度などの値を得られたら、と思いました。
APIでセンサー値が得られる、など情報をお持ちの方教えて頂けませんでしょうか。

Comment: 最初のHoloLensの方はAmbient Light Sensorが明確に記載されていますが、HoloLens2の方は無いですね。HoloLens2の紹介記事だと周囲光(Ambient Light)の影響を受けないカメラという記述が偶にあります。検索するとカメラを使うこんな記事があるので、さらに調べるか試すかしてみてはどうでしょう？ [デジカメを光の明るさ・色の測定器として使う方法](https://www.chiba-c.ed.jp/funako/fttp_kousin/ssh/kyouzai/DigitalCamera_2017a.pdf), [デジタルカメラ画像を用いた照度測定の検討](https://www.ieice.org/publications/conference-FIT-DVDs/FIT2015/data/pdf/I-012.pdf), [スマートフォンのカメラを用いた照度の推定による認知能力低下の注意を運転手に促すアプリケーションの開発](https://pdf.gakkai-web.net/gakkai/ieice/gakusei/23pr/pdf/122.pdf)

Comment: あるいはこちらの記事にヒントがあるかもしれません。[HoloLens 2 ディスプレイのトラブルシューティング](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/hololens/hololens2-display), [ホログラムと操作のトラブルシューティング](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/hololens/hololens-faq)

Comment: kunifさん
ありがとうございます。早速、読んで検討してみます。
助かります。